# Convert Date Time converting weird time

Tags: jsf

i have this code on my xhtml

```
<h:inputHidden id="startDate" value="#{testController.selected.startDate}">
       <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" />
</h:inputHidden>
```

if i input `2013-02-26 17:15` the result of the data inserted on my database is `2013-02-27 01:15`
or if `2013-02-26 05:15` result is `2013-02-26 13:15`

i already inputted a 24 hour date time on the input but i am really confused why it is converting to something else.

*Edit

my goal is.. what ever will be the time inputted by the user on the input, it would be reflected the same in the database. i'm using a datepicker for the input so assuming the time/date input is already correct and is on 24 hour format

Comment: Could it be something to do with timezone?

Comment: updated the question above, for the current thing i want to achieve.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF convertDateTime renders the previous day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351244/jsf-convertdatetime-renders-the-previous-day)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i guess JSF date/time converters defaults by specification to UTC timezone.

so i added this on my web.xml and it worked.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

reference:
[Set a default time zone for f:convertDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490954/set-a-default-timezone-for-fconvertdatetime)