# Cannot change time zone of java web application

Tags: hibernate, jsf, web-applications, time, zone

I have web application with me. It is showing US time. I want it to show Indian time. 
I have tried setting property uing `System.getProperty().setProperty("user.country","IN");` and `System.getProperty().setProperty("user.variant","IN");` but still it is showing use time.

I even tried `Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "IN"));` but in vain.

When I do this

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyy.MMMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa -- z");
System.out.println("Date: "+format.format(new Date()));
```

The result is `Date: 02013.March.14 AD 12:29 AM -- GMT-08:00`.
what am I doing wrong.

It is a JSF 1.1 and Hibernate 3 project deployed in tomcat 6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks lion but this is not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line:

```
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
```

Comment: which is the best place to put this code in my web application so that this could be set as soon as the application become up on server.

Comment: Put this line right after you initialize your `SimpleDataFormat`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyy.MMMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa -- z");
    f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
    System.out.println(f.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing. Is it really US time? JSF defaults to UTC. If it is indeed really US time (e.g. EDT), then it should have explicitly been configured as such in `timeZone` attribute of all `<f:convertDateTime>` tags. All you needed to do would be to change "EDT" to "IST". But this is such an extremely obvious solution that I think that you're actually not running US time, but just UTC.

Your attempt to solve the problem is also confusing. You said and tagged that you're using JSF, but you're not attempting to solve it the JSF way, but the plain Java way. This is really not how you're supposed to convert date/time in JSF. You should use `<f:convertDateTime>` for the job and not `SimpleDateFormat`.

In any case, you need to configure all `<f:convertDateTime>` tags to explicitly set the `timeZone` attribute to `IST`.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.date}">
    <f:convertDateTime timeZone="IST" />
</h:outputText>
```

Note that if you were using JSF 2.x, then you could also have set a `web.xml` context parameter to apply this change applicationwide. See also [Set a default time zone for f:convertDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490954/set-a-default-timezone-for-fconvertdatetime/7491706#7491706).