# Conveter error between util.Date and sql.Date on JPA

Tags: jsf, jpa, primefaces

the atribbute on my bean

```
@Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date data;
```

The date is correctly saved on database

[image]

but in the JSF the date is showing wrong. Days are lost

[image]

the JSF code

```
<p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Data" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{contadores.dataCalendar.time}" >
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
```

Comment: It looks like 2 days difference.

Comment: I'm doing some tests, but I think that I miss something in my JSF

Comment: Sorry @Tiny, this was a test, but the type in bean is util.Date

Comment: You know that convertDateTime uses UTC timezone by default?

Comment: So, I have to change that?

Comment: I Aam totally lost now. Where is the sql Date? And where is it not? Details are important. Debug the sql query if needed etc. It indeed looks 2 days

Comment: You look like to have a timezone inconsistency in 2 places. In at least the JSF side, this is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351244/jsf-convertdatetime-renders-the-previous-day If that still doesn't fix the problem (but at least brings the difference to 1 day), then look in JPA/DB side for other timezone fail. You'd better breakdown the question in two.

Comment: I edit the web.xml and makes no effect

Comment: so when you persist the date, is the SQL correct, and it is stored correct in the DB? and if so then when you retrieve it, is the SQL correct? and are the dates correct in Java after the JPA call? and then in JSF ? do those basic things and you will see where the problem is ...

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7490954/1391249) is too the same in nature.