# ConvertDateTime does not get timezone defined in web.xml

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, jboss-seam

I'm using f:convertDateTime to format a dateTime in a datatable. I set the following context parameter in web.xml to explicitly set the timezone to system timezone:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

For some reason my convertDateTime gets "GMT" always, but the correct timezone is "GMT-03:00". I tried this in a test class to see my timezone:

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
```

which gives me "GMT-03:00".

I'm using JSF 1.2 and JBoss Seam 2.2, the jboss-seam DateTimeConverter is called to make this conversion, I don't know if this is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I'm using JSF 1.2*

The mentioned context param is introduced in JSF 2.0. It's not available in JSF 1.x. See also a.o. [Set a default time zone for f:convertDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490954/set-a-default-time-zone-for-fconvertdatetime). In other words, it's simply never used. Remove it to avoid confusion.

You've 2 options:

1. Explicitly specify `timeZone` in every `<f:convertDateTime>`.

   ```
   <h:xxx ...>
       <f:convertDateTime ... timeZone="GMT-3" />
   </h:xxx>
   ```

   If necessary as application scoped bean property.

   ```
   <h:xxx ...>
       <f:convertDateTime ... timeZone="#{config.timeZone}" />
   </h:xxx>
   ```

   ---
2. Extend the date time converter with a new default time zone (and other properties).

   ```
   public class DefaultDateTimeConverter extends DateTimeConverter {

       public DefaultDateTimeConverter() {
           setType("both");
           setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-3"));
       }

   }
   ```

   ```
   <converter>
       <converter-id>defaultDateTimeConverter</converter-id>
       <converter-class>com.example.DefaultDateTimeConverter</converter-class>
   </converter>
   ```

   And then replace `<f:convertDateTime>` with it.

   ```
   <h:xxx ... converter="defaultDateTimeConverter" />
   ```

Comment: Strange, because i have a project with JSF 2.2 and i just use convertDateTime direct without this "hacks".

Comment: Ok. I already understand. The context param just work in jsf 2.0. Thanks balusC