# Schedule showing wrong end date on Calender Primeface JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, fullcalendar

Hi I try make schedule using primaface but the end date showing one day before the specified date

[image]

**And this bean**

```
 @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();

        lazyEventModel = new LazyScheduleModel() {

            @Override
            public void loadEvents(Date start, Date end) {
                List<Group> listproject = new GroupDAO().retriveAll("", new Object[] {});
                Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar dates = Calendar.getInstance();

                for (int i = 0; i < listproject.size(); i++) {

                    date.setTime(listproject.get(i).getCreateAt());

                    dates.setTime(listproject.get(i).getUpdateAt());

                    addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent(listproject.get(i).getName(), date.getTime(), dates.getTime()));
                    System.out.println(listproject.get(i).getName()+ listproject.get(i).getCreateAt() + listproject.get(i).getUpdateAt());
                }


            }  
        };
    }
```

**The Xhtml**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
template="/user_templates/template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="metadata">
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="content">
    <p:layout>
        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <h:form id="formId">
                <h:panelGrid columnClasses="value">
                    <p:schedule value="#{testBean.lazyEventModel}" timeZone="GMT+7" > <!-- view="agendaWeek" bisa dipake buat search -->
                        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{testBean.onDateSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show()" />
                        <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{testBean.onEventSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show()" />
                    </p:schedule>
                </h:panelGrid>

                 <p:dialog widgetVar="eventDialog" header="Event Details" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip">
        <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails" columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel for="title" value="Titles:" />
        <p:inputText id="title" value="#{testBean.event.title}" required="true" />

        <p:outputLabel for="from" value="From:" />
        <p:calendar id="from" value="#{testBean.event.startDate}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" showTime="true" appendTo="@(body)"  />

        <p:outputLabel for="to" value="To:" />
        <p:calendar id="to" value="#{testBean.event.endDate}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" showTime="true" appendTo="@(body)" />

        <!-- <p:outputLabel for="allDay" value="All Day (see #1164):" />
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="allDay" value="#{testBean.event.allDay}" /> -->

        <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" />
        <p:commandButton id="addButton" value="Save" action="#{testBean.addEvent}" oncomplete="PF('myschedule').update();PF('eventDialog').hide();" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>    
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</ui:define>
```

previously I used Date for set value on cratedAt and updateAt on GroupDAO for get value from database but it show same thing like the picture for the start date and then I change it into Timestamp, and the star date showing like I want but the end date showing like that, and I don't know the problem is

And I just realized just that value have wrong end date

Comment: Which instance of Date class are you using (util)? Can you post also the definition of Group class? Have you tried adding localization in each step (query, lazy load, xhtml)?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info about the [mcve] please. Try dropping templates, includes etc... (as well as the layout etc...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set a default time zone for f:convertDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490954/set-a-default-time-zone-for-fconvertdatetime)

Comment: Oh and 1: it is PrimeFaces (with an s at the end) and 2: The displaying of the date is in the calendar and in no way (technically) schedule related and 3: (I did not downvote yet), see https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive